# pass parameter to href

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

i'm need to pass parameter to href base on the firstname on the list, the name is a link to aonther page that i get via _id that pass on the url .

the issue is that the id dont pass to the url and i get an error

how can i pass data to the url ?

my code :

```
<script>
    const getuser = () => {
        pers.forEach(per => {
            if (document.getElementById("link") == per.FirstName) {
                document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href","/persons/"+per._id);
            }
        })
    }

</script>

<body>
    <h1>Persons</h1>
    <ul>
        <% pers.forEach(function(per) { %>

            <li>
                <a  id="link" onclick="getuser()">
                    <%= per.FirstName %>
                </a>
            </li>

            <% }) %>

    </ul>
```

Comment: `"/persons/?personId="+per._id`. I'd suggest you read up on [what a querystring is and how it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: @Liam plenty of Urls look like `/person/123` - not everything is a query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
if (document.getElementById("link") == per.FirstName) {
```

Will never evaluate true. You're comparing a reference to an HTML element to a (I presume) string `FirstName`.

I can't fathome why you're trying to do this in javascript when you are server-side rendering the page. Just build the HTML inline

```
<ul>
    <% pers.forEach(function(per) { %>
        <li>
            <a href="/persons/<%= per.Id%>">
                <%= per.FirstName %>
            </a>
        </li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Note: Removed `Id` from your element as ids should be unique and you're rendering in a loop!